# How to pass the values in the method

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass the values into the static method called " result";
How can we pass and what kind of arg(0) in the method?

can you please help me to understand the concept and why we need to pass the values as a list? :)

also please help me to find another possible values to store the frequency of elements in the HashMap?

I'm mentioning hr code below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Counting_Triplets {
    
    static long result(List<Long> arr,long r) {
    
        HashMap<Long,Long> left=new HashMap<Long,Long>();
        HashMap<Long,Long> right=new HashMap<Long,Long>();
        
        //to put the frequency values into right
        
        for(long j:arr) {
            
            right.put(j, right.getOrDefault(j, (long) 0)+1);
    
        }
        long count=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {
            
            long mid=arr.get(i);
            long c1=0,c3=0;
            
            //to reduce the frequency of right
            
            right.put(mid, right.getOrDefault(mid, 0l)-1);
            
            if(left.containsKey(mid/r) && mid % r==0) {
                
                c1=left.get(mid/r);
                
            }
            
            if(right.containsKey(mid*r)) {
                c3=right.get(mid*r);
            }
            
            count=count+(c1*c3);
            
            //to increase the left count
            
            left.put(mid, left.getOrDefault(mid, 0l)-1);
            
            }
        return count;
        
        }




    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements :");
        
        int n=s.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println(" Enter the 'r' value :");
        
        int r=s.nextInt();
        
    ArrayList<Long> arr=new ArrayList<Long>();
        
        for(long i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {
            arr[i]=s.nextLong();
        } 
        
        result(arr, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a List, because that's what that method is programmed to accept. Can you be more specific about what you mean by this: How can we pass and what kind of arg(0) in the method? ?

Comment: Third: `arr[i]`is a syntax to add a value to an Array and not to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Your method name is very non-descriptive, and it's very hard to figure out what you are trying to accomplish.

In terms of passing to a method, you are using a list since you have an unknown (at compile time) number of values being passed, i.e. sometimes you want to pass 3 values and another time maybe 35000. A method always has a fixed number of arguments, so we need one of those arguments to be a list or array.

To add items to a List:

```java
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
Object myObject = new Object();
myList.add(myObject);
```

If you don't want to use Lists, you can also use an array, since the number of values *is* known at *runtime*. An array's size does not change dynamically like a List, but you can assign its size during initialization.

```java
static long result(Long[]) {...}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements: ");
    
    int n = s.nextInt();
        
    System.out.println("Enter the 'r' value: ");
        
    int r = s.nextInt();
        
    Long[] arr = new Long[n];
        
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i]=s.nextLong();
    } 
        
    result(arr, r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get full idea what you are trying to achieve, but let's talk about some mistakes:

In here you create an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Long> arr=new ArrayList<Long>();
    
    for(long i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {
        arr[i]=s.nextLong();
    } 
    
    result(arr, r);
}
```

Problems:

1. You treat arraylist as an array, it is wrong concept. Please read about Java Collections API.
   You must refer to an element in a following way:

   arr.get(i)

And here comes the next problem:
Why did you choose long for a counter? Unless you work with a really huge amount of elements (more than an Int can handle), never use any counter except int.

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {
            arr.get(i);
        }
```

Talking of why you should use list in a result method - because it is specified in result method, quite obvious.

```
            void pleaseGiveMeInt(int Number) {
            have some fun with a number
        }
```

If you want to have fun with anything else - than you should choose right variables: double, List, Object, whatever

If my answer confuses you - I can only suggest you to read about methods, functions, data types and Java Documentation/Collections API.

Good luck in the world of Java!